# Use Anchor using Html.MenuLink asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Asp.net MVC4 and i'm trying to add an "anchor" in the Html.MenuLink without rewriting a new MenuLink

Here my the html link

```
<li class="nousjoindre">
    @Html.MenuLink("Join us", "Index", "JoinUs", null, new { @class = "active" })
</li>
```

Resulting in this html when render

```
<li class="join">
    <a href="/JoinUs">Join us</a>
</li>
```

and the target anchor

```
<div>
    <h1 id="PointHere">Point here</h1>
</div>
```

and the MenuLink code

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink( this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues = null, object htmlAttributes = null) 
{
    string currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    string currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");

    if (controllerName == currentController)
    {
        if (htmlAttributes == null) 
            htmlAttributes = new { @class = "selected" };

        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(
            linkText,
            actionName,
            controllerName,
            routeValues,
            htmlAttributes
        );
    }

    return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
}
```

The 4th parameter of the Html.MenuLink is used for adding parameters to the target link, but  that is not what I needed.

I want to have an url like `localhost/JoinUs#PointHere`

Thanks for help

Comment: There's no such `Html.MenuLink` helper built-in ASP.NET MVC 4. Please include the relevant source code of the custom helper you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I forget it!! Here I included the MenuLink code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`following overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) of the Html.ActionLink helper to generate an url with a fragment identifier:

```
return htmlHelper.ActionLink(
    linkText: linkText,
    actionName: actionName,
    controllerName: controllerName,
    protocol: null,
    hostName: null,
    fragment: "some_fragment",
    routeValues: routeValues,
    htmlAttributes: htmlAttributes
);
```

Obviously you will need to adapt your `MenuLink` custom helper to take as additional parameter the `fragment` identifier that will be appended to the url.

And then you will be able to invoke it like this:

```
@Html.MenuLink("Join us", "Index", "JoinUs", null, new { @class = "active" }, fragment: "PointHere")
```